# How do I use local_file resource to save pem file to disk which was created by tls_private_key resource in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to save the `private_key_pem` generated by the `tls_private_key` resource to a file on disk locally using `local_file` resource.

```
resource "tls_private_key" "example" {
  algorithm = "RSA"
  rsa_bits  = 4096
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "generated_key" {
  key_name   = "cloudtls"
  public_key = tls_private_key.example.public_key_openssh
}

resource "aws_instance" "automation" {
  instance_type        = var.instance_type
  ami                  = var.image_id
  iam_instance_profile = aws_iam_instance_profile.ec2_profile.name
  key_name = aws_key_pair.generated_key.key_name
}

resource "local_file" "pem_file" {
  filename = "pemfile.pem"
  #
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you've basically got it. The [`local_file` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/local/r/file.html) takes a `content` parameter which can be an interpolated value. What point are you struggling with specifically?

Comment: I was not sure about how to add the private key contents to the file, but I tried interpolating value like you suggested `content = tls_private_key.example.private_key_pem`and it worked!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The below code saves the private key *(.pem file)* to the specified path.

```
resource "local_file" "cloud_pem" { 
  filename = "${path.module}/cloudtls.pem"
  content = tls_private_key.example.private_key_pem
}
```